# Modify icon of the Flex application for Blackberry-Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, icons, air, blackberry-playbook

Has anybody please found a way to modify/replace the icon of a Playbook program?

Like display a red star on it - to indicate there is new message for the user.

I've tried tracing [NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon and NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4af7-8000.html), but they are both false on Playbook simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking (dynamically changing the icon once the app is installed) is not currently possible.  That will require OS support which is not available and hasn't even been mentioned publicly yet.

The reason it's not possible currently without an API is that everything in your .bar is written to a folder which is read-only to the app itself, icon file and MANIFEST.MF file included.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `blackberry-tablet.xml` and add

```
<icon>
    <image>blackberry-tablet-icon.png</image>
</icon>
```

Comment: No, I'd like to change the icon programmatically during the runtime, not compile-time.